# Add plus sign "+" for positive values with jQuery ui-slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to add plus sign "+" for positive values with jQuery ui-slider? By default the negative sign shows but I want the positive sign as well to show the difference from starting value.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Figuring it out with assistance of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357256/jquery-ui-range-add-plus-symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you have already figured out the solution for it. If not here is the answer.

You can use the `slide` and `create` events for manipulating these values in Slider ,

```
    create : function() {
           //For initialization event 
           var value=$(".slider").slider( "value" );
           $("#amount").val((value > '0') ? ('+'+ value) : value);
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
           //Slide Event
           $("#amount").val((ui.value > '0') ? ('+'+ ui.value) : ui.value);
    }
```

#### Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hk50nhnq/)

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is a huge help. I did end up finding a solution but Stackoverflow deemed my answer 'trivial' and turned it into a comment (see @Ken above). I am using it to determine the difference of change instead of long a scale - useful because the orig. value tends to get lost when it is adjusted. Thanks again for your time. I didn't even think of using the 'create' event. K.